# Update Git remote branch with another remote branch

Tags: git, azure

I'm working with Azure Git.

I have created a remote branch of the master on which I've created a local branch and worked on. Is there a way to update the remote branch from the master (which has progressed since then) without a PR, but by some merging done from Azure itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge from your remote master to your remote branch if you wanted to.
But I'd recommend the following :
In your local branch run the following command to merge whats in your remote master to your local branch :

`git pull origin master --rebase`

This will pull all updates from master to your local branch, then apply your local commits over that. You can follow the instructions in the command line to fix any merge conflicts if there are any.
Once thats done, you should ideally compile and run your code, and if everything is good push your changes to your remote branch with the --force flag

`git push origin <your-branch-name> --force`

Comment: Can this method bypass an Azure policy?

Comment: Whats the policy you are talking about specifically? Do you mean a branch policy on master?

Comment: feature branch policy which doesn't allow commits without a PR

Comment: is the branch policy on the master branch? or on your feature branch of which you have a local copy?

Comment: on both of them

Comment: if you are unable to directly push your code to your feature origin branch, then you have 2 options :
1. Remove the branch policies in your feature branch that prevent direct commits/push
2. Create a new branch from your local feature branch using the command `git branch -b <your-new-branch-name>`, push this new branch to origin `git push origin <your-new-branch>`, and then make a pull request to your feature branch. I don't see any other options. You can run `git pull origin master --rebase` in your new branch before you push that to remote and make a PR from that your your feature branch.